# trigger a keyup without pressing a key C#

Tags: c#, winforms

i wanna trigger a keyup event just by calling the form and not pressing a key

Heres my code:

```
if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    FrmQty fqty = new FrmQty(this);
                    fqty.ProductDetails(dr["ProductID"].ToString(), float.Parse(dr["ProductPrice"].ToString()), lblTransno.Text);
                    fqty.txtQty.Text = "1";
                    fqty.txtQty_KeyUp();//i wanna trigger it here by pressing "Enter" key. its an event from FormQty
                    fqty.ShowDialog();
                }
```

Comment: if you have an event associated with a key down, inside your FrmQty, you can make it public and call it from outside like `myForm_KeyDown(null,null)`. In your question you don't specify which key you want to press/release.

Comment: @AmoRobb `Enter` is the key i wanna trigger with it. is used `txtQty_KeyUp(sender, e)` but it throws an error, since its in the other Form.

Comment: Put the code you have in the event into a different method. Now call the method from the event and from everywhere you need that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```cs
   private void myForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs  e)
   {

      if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
           MyEnterKeyDownFunc();
      else
      {
        //your other keys management
      }
   }

   public void MyEnterKeyDownFunc()
   {
      //do your enter key down stuff here

       // if you want to modify anything on the UI, you should make sure it 
       // is invoked in the GUI thread. Maybe something like:
    if (aControl.InvokeRequired)
     {
         aControl.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                // GUI modifications
            });
      }
     else
     {
         // GUI modifications
      }      
   }
```

Now you can call `MyEnterKeyDownFunc()` from outside your class

Answer (score 0):

One (probably better) solution is to make a handler function public and simple call it.
Another may be a simulation of key press using `SendKeys`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=net-5.0